# Layout preview not working?

Tags: android-studio

I can't see the layout. This is what is showing up. What could be the problem?

[image]

Works fine on my phone, btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close Studio. Remove the project from the list. Instead of opening it again, import it.